# Qual deve ser nosso elevator pitch? (Frase de efeito para divulgação)

Tags: debate, big-7, divulgação

Existem algumas perguntas que todo novo site da rede deve fazer antes de se graduar. Isso está descrito no [blog oficial](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/).

Algumas é cedo para se fazer, outras nós já estamos fazendo. Veja em [big-7](/questions/tagged/big-7).

Eu achei que era cedo pra fazer essa, mas o Gabe está discutindo isso no [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/13357867#13357867).

Algumas ideais bem legais foram sugeridas por ele como "Deu pau? Pergunte em português" ou "Os bugs que aqui gorjeiam/Não gorjeiam como lá".

Mas elas sofrem de problemas diplomáticos. Elas são boas para brasileiros. Mas nosso site é para lusófonos.

Precisamos encontrar uma frase que traga as pessoas para o site e que funcione bem para todos os países.

Dê sua contribuição. Vai que ela seja escolhido. Quem escolher o melhor vai poder comprar, com seu próprio dinheiro, um doce na padaria da esquina :)

Answer (score 13):

Bom, aqui vai:

Mais comum em Portugal seria `esta m***a não funciona` que daria a pergunta:

> Essa m***a não funciona? Pergunta em Português

Numa forma menos ofensiva:

> ## Tem um bug? Pergunte em Português

Comment: "Essa m***a não funciona" também é um clássico em português brasileiro: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7MR0Za-Ikno#t=03m29s

Comment: @Piovezan Verdade :) Esse vídeo é só cara*****! Vocês é que curtem :)

Comment: A gente e o povo de Coimbra :) heheheh

Comment: E __Não funciona? Pergunte em português.__?

Comment: @dmvianna Pode resultar, coloca como uma resposta e deixa que a comunidade se manifeste através do voto nessa tua ideia :)

Answer (score 7):

Parafraseando Camões:

`Por bugs nunca dantes fixados` em Português

`Por mares nunca dantes programados` em Português

Answer (score 6):

> Sua pilha de problemas estourou? Hora de pedir ajuda em português.

Comment: +1, mas é incrível como o Português nos força a usar o dobro dos caracteres necessários para expressar o mesmo pensamento em Inglês.

Answer (score 2):

`Não funciona? Pergunte em português.`

Answer (score 2):

> **Stack Overflow está aqui**

Tenho ouvido gente aqui chamar o site de "stack", ou até as perguntas de "stacks". Nessa linha dá pra encurtar (mas gosto menos):

> Stack está aqui

Answer (score 1):

`Conhecimento em computação para quem usa "Olá Mundo!".`